# Newbie to play framework: how to convert play project to eclipse project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

Sorry if my question seems dumb to you(it certainly does to me)- the play docs mention use of "eclipse" command to convert a play project to eclipse project. My questions are

(a) Where is this eclipse file? Is it a BAT file (Windows) or EXE?
(b) Separately there is mention of "if you want to grab the available source jars" - which source Jars are referred to here? Play framework's source Jars? What difference do they make? Or do they refer to the play project's source jars? I am pretty confused here....

EDIT- Pls also answer the second part of my question (point b) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`eclipse` is an inner command of [Play's console](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/PlayConsole)

Just go to folder with your app run console with the `play` command and then run `eclipse` (check also `help play` for other options as mentioned in the doc).

You can also do it directly in you powershell by using `play eclipse` .

Answer (score 1):

**To generate eclipse project files you need to:**

1. Open command line (cmd.exe)
2. go to folder with your app
3. run `play` or `play debug` command
4. Once play will start, do `eclipse with-source=true` command.

this will generate eclipse project files with proper links to library source code.

Every time you will change your sbt configuration, you will need to rerun this command.

Edit(b):
Play(via sbt), will download source code of play framework and all libraries, you added manually to your project. Generated project files will have proper references to these libraries as well as corresponding source code. Sources contain documentation and help. Eclipse will show you this documentation upon request (ctrl+space for example). Also, you will have a opportunity to take a look on libraries internals. Sometimes this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about playframework 1, but in playframework 2 I type play eclipse (not eclipsify as the play web says) inside the project directory. Also javac needs to be on the path

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Add the SBT Eclipse plugin details to the plugins.sbt file, which is found in  –> project.

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
   ```
2. Move to the project root folder on the command prompt and run the following Activator command.

   ```
   D:\My_Learnings>cd Learning_Play_App  
   D:\My_Learnings\Learning_Play_App>activator eclipse
   ```

Now you can see the Eclipse project related files in the root project folder.

For more read [here](https://dzone.com/articles/export-play-project-as-eclipse-project).